# Delphi Win32 and JAVA?

Tags: java, delphi, winapi

Wondering if you can help. We use a product called Nethelpdesk. It is supposedly written in Delphi Win32. (I am a sysadmin and know little of code work) Basically the developer cant help us with an issue and we are looking to see if anyone else has any clues.

When running their app (nethelpdesk = nhd) if Java is open their app is SO slow. This is on any machine, including mine which is a i7 \ SSD \ 16GB ram running at 5GB usage and 8% processor average.

Close NHD and I can have 15 java apps open plus 12 other pieces of software and the machine flys.

Reopen their app and the system comes to a screeching halt. Windows stutter, sound can cut out if streaming, and response of the NHD app can take 30 seconds or more for each button hit.

Close JAVA and NHD speeds up.

All machines run great with tons of apps open UNTIL NHD is opened.

If JAVA is closed NHD runs very well.

The developers cant help and we are just looking to be pointed in any direction.

Comment: Delphi produces native Win32 applications, and the only effect it could possibly have on Java apps is too much RAM, disk I/O, or CPU use. Since we can't see the source or any monitoring tools you have access to in order to investigate which of those it might be, it's really not possible for anyone here to help you. The developers should know what their app is doing and be able to tell what the problem might be, and then be able to investigate it (or at least guide you to what to check). Sorry, but voting to close as off-topic (it probably should be "too localized").

Comment: Do you have this app source code? The best I can say is it have nothing to do with Delphi itself. Only a developer with access to the source code can look and search the cause of what you're experiencing.

Comment: Maybe it uses CPU-squeezing spinlocks instead of timer-based Sleep(...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I was a Delphi developer. At that time I noticed that running Outlook caused severe performance issues whenever I was stepping through code with the debugger. This behaviour was similar to what you describe: either process was fine until they were concurrent. Eventually I discovered that this was related to the way OLE messages were handled. Both processes had a tendency to stall message queues, so they slowed one another in a feedback loop.

I suspect an interaction along these lines is the root of your problems. This on its own doesn't help you but it might give your developers some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor with the procmon and check what the application is doing or what it is accessing. My guess GDI (graphic subsystem) ... but it can be anything else.